# Why are labor, capital, and land traditionally denoted by the letters L, K, and T?

Tags: history-economic-thought

AFAIK, at least in the English-speaking world, labor, capital, and land are (in economics) usually denoted by the letters *L*, *K*, and *T*.

Who first popularized the use of these letters and why?

My uneducated guesses are that:

*L* would certainly make sense in English.
*K* I think is from the German *Kapital*.
*T* I think is from the French or Latin *Terre* or *Terra*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing (sorry) that $T$ for *terre* comes from the [Physiocrats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiocracy)' work. K for capital is easiest than $c$ (for consumption).

Btw, labor is not always $L$ but sometimes $N$ depending of if you mean labor force vs working population (or hours). And I've no ideas why $N$!